# Pass control to a DLL

Tags: vb.net

My file-upload function used to show it's progress in a ProgressBar, but now that I moved it into a DLL this is no longer possible.

I'd like to do something like this (in the dll):

```
Public Function uploadfile(ByVal name As String, ByVal path As String, ByVal identifier As Integer,ByVal control As ProgressBarThingyHere,ByVal toProgressBar As Boolean) As String
    'snipped unimportant code
    If toprogressbar then
        SendFileWithProggress(path,control)
    else
        SendFileNoProgress(path)
    end if
End Function

    'Send File
    Private Sub SendFileNoProgress(ByVal path As String)
        sendfile(path, NULL, False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendFileWithProggress(ByVal path As String, ByVal control As ProgressBarThingyHere)
        sendfile(path, control, True)
    End Sub
```

So that I can just call (pseudo code)

```
dll.uploadfile("filename","path",fileID,Form1.ProgressBar1,true)
```

or

```
dll.uploadfile("filename","path",fileID,NULL,false)
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: the progress bar should be in your calling form, so the DLL should implement a callback mechanism that notifies the main caller of the file update progress (maybe passing in a percentage as the parameter).

Comment: How do I let the callback know what to 'report' to? I've never used one before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
Public Class YourUploadingClassInTheDLL
   Public Event BytesAreComing(ByVal percent As Integer)
   Public Event LoadingFinished()

   private Sub loader(Byval reportStatus as Boolean)

      Dim percent as Integer = 0
      ' load the file in a loop maybe
      Do
          ' ...

          if reportStatus Then
            ' report the percentage to the client by raising an event 
            RaiseEvent BytesAreComing(percent)
          End If
    While ( ... )

    RaiseEvent LoadingFinished()
   End Sub

   Public Sub LoadWithStatusBar()
      loader(True);
   End Sub

   Public Sub LoadWithOutStatusBar()
      loader(False);
   End Sub

End Class
```

And in the client code:

```
Private MySplendidDll as MyDLL

Public Sub Main
   MySplendidDll = New MyDLL
   AddHandler MySplendidDll.BytesAreComing, AddressOf BytesAreComingHandler
End Sub

 Private Sub BytesAreComingHandler(byval percent as integer)
   ' update the progress bar
 End Sub
```

Remember to also remove the event handler when you're finished.